# Frame function in Wand does't work on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, frame, wand

I am trying to add a border around an image using the `image.frame` function in Python Wand:

```
image.frame(width=2, height=2)
```

This seems to work fine on a Raspberry Pi, but converts the image to grayscale on the Mac. Any clues?

```py
from wand.image include *
from wand.display include *

#  tryme.jpg is color jpg image
image=Image(filename="tryme.jpg")
image.frame(width=2, height=2)

display(image)
```

Should display a color picture with 2 pixel border around it.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me on ImageMagick 6.9.10.57 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra using Python Wand 0.5.5. Note my syntax is different from your.

[image]

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='lena.jpg') as img:
    img.frame(width=10, height=10)
    img.save(filename='lena_frame.jpg')
    display(img)
```

[image]

ADDITION:

It actually fails with ImageMagick 7 as per the question asked above. I have reported a bug to the Python Wand developer.

Comment: This is just weird.  I tried two different Macs: 
one running OS X El Capitain, ImageMagic 7.0.8-53 Q16, Wand 0.55; the other running OS X Mojave, ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16, and Wand 0.55.  I tried both Python 3.7.4 and Python 2.7.10.  I used your syntax and I tried different pictures - both PNG and JPG.  All produce a grayscale image.

Comment: FYI - using "convert" from the command line works fine. e.g.,  convert tryme.jpg -border 2x2 out.jpg

Comment: -border is not the same as -frame. Two different functions that can produce similar results. Can you post a link to one of your input images? Perhaps it is corrupt?

Comment: I tried multiple images, all of with the same result.  Here's a sample image: http://www.ourbunch.net/tryme.jpg

Comment: It works fine for me with IM 6.8.10.58 Q16 Mac OSX. But it fails with your image on IM 7.0.10.58 HDRI Q16 with an error message on Wand 0.5.5 (strangely). But on IM 7 with Wand 0.5.6 (under development), I do get a grayscale image with a color frame when specifying matte='red'. I have reported this to the Python Wand developer. It happens with other images as well.

Comment: This is now fixed in Python Wand 0.5.6 (released today)